# Why is $g(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}fd\mu$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb R$ when $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R,\mu)$ and $\mu$ is de Lebesgue measure?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is de Lebesgue Measure, how can I prove that $g(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}fd\mu$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not, there would be a $\varepsilon>0$, such that, for every $\delta>0$, there exist $x_\delta,y_\delta\in\mathbb R$, with
$$
|x_\delta-y_\delta|<\delta \quad\text{and}\quad
|g(x_\delta)-g(x_\delta)|\ge\varepsilon.
$$
In particular, for $\delta=1/n$ we would have sequences $\{x_n\}$, $\{y_n\}$,
such that
$$
|x_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}\quad\text{and}\quad
|g(x_n)-g(x_n)|\ge\varepsilon.
$$

Case I. The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and hence it contains a convergent subsequence $x_{k_n}\to x^*$. Clearly $y_{k_n}\to x^*$ as well, and as $g$ is continuous, then $g(x_{k_n})\to g(x^*)$, $g(y_{k_n})\to g(x^*)$ and thus
$|g(x_{k_n})-g(x_{k_n})|\to 0$. Contradiction.

Case II. The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded and hence it contains a subsequence $x_{k_n}\to \infty$ or $x_{k_n}\to -\infty$. Consider the first subcase (the second one is treated similarly). We can choose the sequence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ and $\{y_{k_n}\}$, so that
$$
x_{k_1}<y_{k_1}<x_{k_2}<y_{k_2}<\cdots<x_{k_n}<y_{k_n}<\cdots
$$
Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}|f|\,dx\ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty \int_{x_{k_j}}^{x_{k_{j+1}}}|f|\,dx
\ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty |g({x_{k_{j+1}}})-g({x_{k_j}})|\ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty\varepsilon=\infty.
$$
Again leading to a contradiction.